# Storing directory paths with files inside those directories as observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program where I store directory inputs with files inside of that directory e.g.

```
C:/Documents
 C:/Documents/1.jpg
 C:/Documents/2.jpg
```

What would be the best data structure to store it so I could easily loop for just input directories or just by files or when I delete the directory the file would be delete as well.

I was thinking about using dictionary, but it has to also be observable.

What I use currently

```
private ObservableCollection<string> inputDirectories new ObservableCollection<string>();;
private ObservableCollection<string> inputFiles = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

This solution doesn't really give me a lot of choices, I can't just get input episodes for certain input directory since they are in no way connected. When I delete inputDirectory I would have to loop and compare the input directory with my inputfiles to delete only files for that directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the *DirectoryInfo* class from the *System.IO* namespace rather than a plain string, you can get the files included in this directory via the *GetFiles* method. You can then expose the list of all Files in a Property using LINQ. Just make sure that you fire a *OnPropertyChanged* for this property whenever the *inputDirectories* change.

```
private ObservableCollection<DirectoryInfo> inputDirectories = new ObservableCollection<DirectoryInfo>();

inputDirectories.Add(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Documents"));

public IEnumerable<string> Files => inputDirectories.SelectMany(d => GetFilesInDirectory(d));

private IEnumerable<string> GetFilesInDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
  {
     return directory.GetFiles().Select(x => x.FullName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking about using dictionary, but it has to also be observable.

There is no such class that implements both the `IDictionary` interface and the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface available in the .NET Framework, i.e. there is no hybrid between a dictionary and an `ObservableCollection<T>` available, so you will have to create your own custom class.

You could take a look at the `ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` class provided here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/

An observable dictionary is indeed what you need.

Comment: Link seems to be dead, latest capture of it on the Internet Archive is at https://web.archive.org/web/20200108163203/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/

Answer (score -1):

You should store directory in Dictionary. Key should be directory and value should be inner directory or file.

Comment: Yes but I also need it to be observable

Comment: You have to write your own custom dictionary by inheriting existing dictionary and raise event on adding updating or deleting objects.